# How convert Bitmap to byte array and back without quality reduction?

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap

When I convert a picture into bytes and back, the quality deteriorates a lot. How to do it without reducing quality?

I need to save the photo in the database or send it to the server. I can consider other options to do this.

```
public static byte[] fromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
    return stream.toByteArray();
}
public static Bitmap toBitmap(byte[] bytes) {
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
}
```

Comment: Storing image as bytes in db is not a good way to store image. You can save image's device path in db and then display the image using any library like Picasso.

Comment: You can save Images inside [`getFilesDir()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getFilesDir%28%29) and save corresponding path to database . To send to server you can use Multipart request ..

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good way to save the picture in the database directly. The best way is to upload pictures to the server in a directory and save the picture path in the database. [Here](http://www.androidcodefinder.com/blog/2018/02/04/android-upload-image-to-server-using-php-mysql/) you can find out a complete tutorial to upload the picture on the server and save its path in the MYSQL database.

Answer (score 1):

> How to do it without reducing quality?

Use a lossless image format, such as PNG.

Comment: accidentaly press an enter happen this to me, But when I find something better I found here the same way!!!!